# Query to retrieve a BOOL from Parse DB for the current logged in user, which will determine what segue to go to

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a Query that will access a BOOL from the current logged in user's data from my Parse database.

So far, when the user creates an account, the boolean **profileCompleted** is automatically assigned to **NO** as the user has not finished creating their profile. (This takes place in RegisterViewController.m).

When they have signed up, they are taken to the root navigation controller (FindFriendsViewController.m). Now from there, it checks if the user is logged in,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    //The User is logged in
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
}
else {
    //The User is not logged in
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
}
```

Now, the problem I am having is I want a query (when a user is logged in) to check if their BOOL value **profileCompleted** is set to True or False. I have checked the Parse documentation, but just can't get it to work.

Whether the BOOL is true or false will determine what segue to go to next. (If profileCompleted = true, they will be taken to the home page. If profileCompleted = false, they will be taken to the profile editor).

EDIT2:

My code now looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
BOOL profileCompleted = [currentUser[@"profileCompleted"] boolValue];

if (currentUser) {
    NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);

    if (profileCompleted){
        NSLog(@"Profile has been completed");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Profile has not been completed");
    }

}
else {
    //Then User is not logged in
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}

}
```

No matter what the values are in the database (True or False), I'm always getting "Profile has not been completed" on my output.

EDIT3:

The only place in my code where **profileCompleted** gets assigned a value is in my RegisterViewController.m file:

```
    ...
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser[@"firstName"] = firstName;
    newUser[@"surname"] = surname;
    newUser.password = password;
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser[@"profileCompleted"] = @NO; <--- HERE

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: Is the `profileCompleted` a column in your user class or is it a separate class (Which is what your code says)?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry about that, I have updated the post.
profileCompleted is in the User Class along with the other registration details, such as first name, last name, email address, username etc.

Comment: So, where does it get assigned the value of "yes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just retrieve the `profileCompleted` value from the current user -

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
BOOL profileCompleted= [[currentUser[@"profileCompleted"] boolValue];

if (profileCompleted) {
   ...
}
```

if the data held in PFUser may be stale (e.g. profile was completed somewhere else) then you will need to fetch the user -

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser != nil) {
    [currentUser fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        BOOL profileCompleted= [[object[@"profileCompleted"] boolValue];

        if (profileCompleted) {
           ...
        }
    }
  }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but now no matter what the values are in the database (True or False), I'm always getting "Profile has not been completed" on my output.

I've edited the thread to show you the full code. Cheers.

Comment: Are you updating the `profileCompleted` value of the currentUser in this app or somewhere else? ie. Does the local data need to be updated?

Comment: Thank you so much Paul.
I really appreciate it.